Flutter app: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries
I want to my flutter project on a virtual device in Android Studio, but it always doesn't work. I always receive this code error
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\NCKH\right_premium_brain\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
Error launching application on sdk gphone16k x86 64.


Can you add your package name?

This question is similar to: Targeting SDK Android Q results in Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This solution work for me!
I added android:extractNativeLibs="true" on my AndroidManifest see below.


first You need to clear cache with the commands
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk

Make sure that enable of multidex in build gradle
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

If thats Not work than repair the Corrupted Files
flutter pub cache repair


android:extractNativeLibs="true"
